# how to combine react and express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, pug

I worked on my client and server side code separately. I now managed to get them both working simultaneously in the same project but i dont know how to makethe two work together. I am using javascript/node/react/redux/webpack on client side and node/express/jade on the server side.

## index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import store from "./store/index";
import App from "./components/App";
import Home from './components/_HomePage';
import User from './components/_AboutPage';

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

this loads up a react page on port 3000, where i can add stuff to a list.

## server.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var index = require('./server/routes/index');
var users = require('./server/routes/users');
var catalog = require('./server/routes/catalog');

var db = require('./db/db');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'server/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
//app.use(express.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/catalog', catalog);

// Connect to MySQL on start
db.connect(db.MODE_PRODUCTION, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to MySQL.')
    process.exit(1)
  } else {
    app.listen(3001, function() {
      console.log('Listening on port 3001...')
    })
  }
})

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

this file loads up the server on port 3001 , which can also be opened as a webpage. It connects my server side to a mysql database and presents the information there on the webpage.

So now i have these 2 webpages, which can run simultaneously, but how do i create 1 page from that?

i am using jade views, so im guessing that my server is going to have to provide these jade views together with database data. And i should forget about the sever side page and just treat it as a service to the client side?

Comment: `I now managed to blend them together. But i don't see how to combine them.` I don't understand. You either did it or you didn't ?!

Comment: edited, i ment that i dont know how to make them work together

Comment: If you say you want to merge `express` with `react`, the answer is you can't. One is serverside and the other is client side. You create endpoints with `express` and serve data to client(`React`). Than you handle the display part in `react`. For the last part of your question, `jade views` are for serverside rendering from what I know, so you either go full serverside with those, or combine `express.js` with `React.js` as I said in the first place.

Comment: You want to serve a react app with expressjs? Right? And as of right now your react app is served using webpack?

Comment: are express and webpack not complimentary? i thought webpack was for bundling. I know that i can't actually merge them, i am whondering how i send data from express to react

Comment: @jelte, the answer to `i am whondering how i send data from express to react`, is in my first comment. This link can help you with that https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: "how i send data from express to react" — You respond to Ajax requests.

Comment: you need to create a bundle first using webpack

Comment: whats the standard methodology for communication between express and react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Express for the backend (Rest API) and React for the frontend (you can access the API using package like Axios, superagent, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you'll need to write your Express app as a RESTful app (Make it return JSON), then make API calls using React, and then render the response. There is a lot more to it, but that's more or less how it works. Here is a simple tutorial on creating a REST API https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd